# How to crossreference javascript class-properties?

Tags: javascript, class, scope

In a project i experience problems with a javascript-scope. This is a basic question, but since im relatively new to js, it is hard to see the problem with this code.

The exception i got is: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstProperty' of undefined.

[The jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XMR6n/1/)

The code from the fiddle:

```
var someClass = function(){
  var _someClass = {
    firstProperty: 'hello world',
    secondProperty: _someClass.firstProperty, // This line is not working like I expected it to work 
  }   

  return _someClass;
}

var someObject = new someClass();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to reference `firstProperty`, then you can use something like this:

```
var someClass = function() {

  var _someClass = new (function() {
    this.firstProperty = 'hello world';
    this.secondProperty = this.firstProperty;
  })(); 

  return _someClass;
}

var someObject = new someClass();

console.log(someObject.firstProperty);
console.log(someObject.secondProperty);
```

See it on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8frDY/).

Comment: I'm just qurious, why the `new(function(){})()`?

Comment: @Loupax It's just to set the context of `this`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `_someClass.firstProperty` is not yet defined. To make this work you should do something like this:

```
var someClass = function(){    
    var _someClass = {};
    _someClass.firstProperty = 'hello world';
    _someClass.secondProperty = _someClass.firstProperty;

    return _someClass;
}

// The new here isn't actually necesary, 
// since the object is created at the first 
// line of the function. I actually don't 
// know what happens here
var someObject = new someClass();
```

Also, to avoid future headaches, keep in mind that JS does not have classes. `someClass` is:

1. An object
2. A function
3. And since functions are objects and can have properties, you can use it as an object constructor but now I'm going off topic so I'll stop

This will help you look up more relevant information in the future